# A non-painful way to compile lzma library on Windows with Cmake/CLion?

Tags: c, cmake, clion, lzma, xz

I have spent 2 days on this problem, and still have no idea how to do it.

All I am trying to do is build a program, or rather function, in C that would take in a compressed lzma file, and extract it on Windows. I am doing it with CLion, with Cygwin 64 3.0.1.

Sound easy? Probably, except for the fact that all method I tried just simple does not work.

Let me get this out of the way first that I am not familiar with Cmake, so that is pretty much why I am asking for advice.

Methods I have tried:

1)

Searching many code on github, I simply see them do

```
#include <lzma.h>
```

Nice, just does not work on Windows. When I compile, I got the error:

```
undefined reference to `lzma_stream_decoder'
undefined reference to `lzma_code'
```

Googling tell me that I am lacking the library for lzma development, and the solution is simply do a sudo apt, and...  you guess it: not for Windows.

2)

Maybe it is a Cmake thing, so let's try to compile with simple gcc first. I grab a simple decompress code with    `#include <lzma.h>` and tried to compile it on Ubuntu. Awesome, everything went smoothly.

Back to Windows, I opened up the Cygwin terminal. Oh of course In Cygwin, I have downloaded liblzma-devel.

Compile is running great to. BUT when firing up the executable:

```
cygwin1.dll and cyglzma-5.dll are missing
```

What the... Even when I specifically downloaded those files and put them to the same folder with the executable, it still fails to start correctly.

3)

Back to Clion/Cmake.

I have looked in to the [Lzma SDK](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) and no avail. What code should I write to the Cmake file? I cannot find any guide that says how to make use of this in C, let alone compile it using Cmake.

Googling "Cmake Lzma" lead me to the [FindLibLZMA](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLibLZMA.html), which I have no idea what they are writing about. I still have no clue what line to put into my CmakeList.txt file, like `add_library` or `find_package`... nope, nothing.

4)

Finally, [Xz Utils](https://tukaani.org/xz/)... the most extensive Lzma tool as far as I can understand, and of course somehow, it also does not work.

I put the file FindLibLZMA.cmake (which I pull down from github) into a folder called Cmake. Then I added

```
find_package(LibLZMA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

into the CmakeList.txt file. Then I set the `LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR` in the FindLibLZMA.cmake file to the folder include of the Xz Utils for Windows... and u guess it, compilation error:

```
#   LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER  - True if lzma_auto_decoder() is found (required).
#   LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER  - True if lzma_easy_encoder() is found (required).
#   LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET   - True if lzma_lzma_preset() is found (required).
```

All these library or something are required, yet where are they? The compiler could not find it, so yeah... again, I am stuck.

I have been trying from yesterday, and I am still stuck.

So please, I am very tired now. Any kind soul would tell me how to make the Lzma library work with Cmake on Windows...Please...Please. Thank you!

Comment: For the first example, you need to *link* with the actual library file. With CMake you do that with [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: Again, not familiar with Cmake, but if I want to use target_link_library, am I need to ADD_LIBRARY first? And If I do that, I need to know all the files in the library? How can I know that?

Comment: You can use a full path to an on-disk library if you want. As in `target_link_libraries(YourExecutableTarget "C:\\Path\\To\\library.lib")`

Comment: Also, [`find_package(LibLZMA REQUIRED)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLibLZMA.html) should set `LIBLZMA_LIBRARIES` that you can pass to `target_link_libraries`. As in `target_link_libraries(YourExecutableTarget ${LIBLZMA_LIBRARIES})`. Or better yet use the imported target `LibLZMA::LibLZMA` (as in `target_link_libraries(YourExecutableTarget LibLZMA::LibLZMA)`)

Comment: As only the second variant allows you to build the program successfully, I would suggest to stay on it and provide more details about the error. Start with the exact error message and the files location (executable, libraries).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude).

For anyone happen to google this, in order to make Xz Utils (the method 4 I tried) to work on Cmake with Clion, I am being very 101 here for any newbie like me now:

1) Create a folder named Cmake in your project source folder.

2) Put the file [FindLibLZMA.Cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindLibLZMA.cmake) into that folder.

3) Add these lines to your CMakeList.txt

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Cmake")
find_package(LibLZMA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(DukasCompiler ${LIBLZMA_LIBRARIES})
```

4) Open the FindLibLZMA.Cmake, and at the beginning, add

```
set(LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR "LINK")
```

with "LINK" is the link to the include folder that you have downloaded from [XZ Utils](https://tukaani.org/xz/) for Windows.

And you are good to go.

THAT BEING SAID:  lzma_stream_decoder only accept .xz file, not .lzma file. So yeah, I am back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too afraid by calling Ada from C, there is a standalone decoder for .lzma files in the open-source [Zip-Ada](https://unzip-ada.sourceforge.io/) project. The difficulty may be to find a relatively recent version of GNAT (the GCC compiler for Ada) running on Cygwin. The up-to-date versions for Windows are usually MinGW-ish.